# Type mismatch when I enter string for Int in one of the form parameter when I submit form in spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a jsp form as following :

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="command" action="RouteGradesGoals.html" >
<tr>
   <td class="style4" colspan="2">
    Goal</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <form:input path="goal" type="text" id="goal" style="width:200px;" />
     </td>
     <td colspan="2">
         <form:errors path="goal" cssClass="error" />
     </td>
 </tr>
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" id="Button3" 
                        class="submitButton" />
</form:form>
```

As you see there is only one parameter goal in the command object and it is of type int in the command object.

But when I submit the form I gets this error by passing string for int in the goal param:

{"detail":"An error has occured while processing the request: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors\nField error in object 'command' on field 'goal': rejected value [sadfasd]; codes [typeMismatch.command.goal,typeMismatch.goal,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [command.goal,goal]; arguments []; default message [goal]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'goal'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"sadfasd\"]"}

The controller has a simple method to process this form as given below:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/RouteGradesGoals.html", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String addInventoryGoal(@ModelAttribute( "command" ) InventoryGoal goal, HttpServletRequest request,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){
        inventoryGoalValidator.validate(goal, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "RouteGradesGoals";
        }

        // do processing of the command object 
        return "RouteGradesGoals";

    }
```

Command object is as follows :

```
public class InventoryGoal {

private Integer goal;

public Integer getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }

    public void setGoal(Integer goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }

}
```

This is how I have added the message resolver in the context xml file :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have added these properties in the messages.properties

```
typeMismatch.command.goal=invalid goal1
typeMismatch.goal=invalid goal2
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=invalid goal2
typeMismatch=invalid goal3
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Forerunner Webservice</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ids.forerunner.web.configuration.WebConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>mysql</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <!-- The CORS filter with parameters -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ids.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <!-- Note: All parameters are options, if ommitted CORS Filter
             will fall back to the respective default values.
          -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
            <param-value>3600</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>APIProtectionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ids.forerunner.filter.APIProtectionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>APIProtectionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

in the WebConfig.java I am importing resources as given below:

@ImportResource({"classpath:/META-INF/spring/forerunner-service.xml","/WEB-INF/webapp-servlet.xml"})

webapp-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ids.forerunner.webapp.controllers" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/forerunner_style.css" location="/forerunner_style.css" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean class="com.ids.forerunner.webapp.interceptor.ForerunnerRequestInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="messageSource" class=" org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:message-webapp-error" />
</bean>

<!--    <util:properties id="tophireProperties" location="classpath:tophire.properties" /> --> 

</beans>
```

forerunner-service.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Enables automatic mapping of fund objects to and from JSON -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml" />

    <bean id="contactFormValidator" class="com.ids.forerunner.webapp.validator.ContactFormValidator" />
    <bean id="inventoryGoalValidator" class="com.ids.forerunner.webapp.validator.InventoryGoalValidator" />
    <bean id="anchorAreaValidator" class="com.ids.forerunner.webapp.validator.AnchorAreaValidator" />

    <bean class="com.ids.forerunner.util.ForerunnerInitializer"/>
    <bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingFiles" value="classpath*:/dozer-bean-mappings.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Setup spring to pull in @Controller, @RequestMapping, etc. Configuration 
        scans specified packages for classes configured as Spring managed beans and 
        automatically sets up objects annotated with @Controller, @Service etc. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ids.forerunner.web" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"></bean>

    <!-- Configures view for returning JSON to the client -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"
        p:contentType="text/plain"></bean>

    <!-- maps handler methods based on HTTP paths -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list id="beanList">
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Converts JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/" p:suffix=".jsp">
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="taskList" class="com.forerunner.cronjobs.TaskList">
        <property name="taskList">
            <list>
                <bean name="sessionTask" class="com.forerunner.cronjobs.SessionCronTask"></bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.forerunner.cronjobs.ForerunnerCronJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="taskList" value-ref="taskList" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cronTrigger" class="com.forerunner.cronjobs.ForerunnerTrigger">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jobDetail" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the message-webapp-error.properties I have properties as follows :

```
typeMismatch.command.goal=invalid goal1
typeMismatch.goal=invalid goal2
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=invalid goal2
typeMismatch=invalid goal3
```

Form is posted to this url http:///forerunner/webapp/RouteGradesGoals.html

Can someone please tell me how can I prevent such error and in such scenerios return a valid error message.

Comment: please add your web.xml and other relevant configuration.

Comment: Now you have me confused you haev multiple `MessageSources` if I read your question correctly. Also your configuration leads to duplication of beans as both your `ContextLoaderListener` as well as the `DispatcherServlet` load the `webapp-servlet.xml`. You have a `WebConfig` class make sure it isn't competing/overriding things in your xml or vice-versa (why not remove the need of the xml?).

Answer (score 4):

Configure a `MessageSource` and provide a message for one of the shown error codes

- `typeMismatch.command.goal`
- `typeMismatch.goal`
- `typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer`
- `typeMismatch`

Which provides messages from most specific to least specific.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class=" org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</bean>
```

This `MessageSource` will load a `messages.properties` (or locale specific one) from the root of the classpath. Add it and fill it accordingly

```
typeMismatch.command.goal=The goal needs to be a valid number.
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=The given input is not a valid number.
```

Now with this content for your case the first message will be shown, for other `typeMismatch` errors on `Integer` fields the second one will be shown.

For more information on a `MessageSource` see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) and [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html). More information on error code generation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion).

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum , I have added these properties to my messsages.properties but no luck and getting the same error.

Comment: If it isn't working you have misconfigured your messagesource. Add some configuration details to your initial post.

Comment: This is what I have added in the context.xml                        <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">      <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />  and I can see messages are getting resoved from this property file  when I access them in jsp using <spring:message> tag library

     <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
 </bean>

Comment: And what is where configured? Please add the configuration to your question. If the `messageSource` is configured in the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` but everything else in the `ContextLoaderListener` it isn't visible and as such resolving will fail.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I have added configuration, but let me know if you still want to know more of the configuration.